# How to remove sudo privilege for default user in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

Hi I have created a machine in openstack environment. This has a default user called ubuntu and it has sudo privilege.

Now I have created a different user called administrator and gave sudo privilege for user and trying to remove sudo privilege for default user "ubunut".

How can i implement it. Even if i try to delete and recreate it says sshd process is using ubuntu user so cannot delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might involve two steps

#### 1.Remove ubuntu from the group with root power (in ubuntu sudo)

try 

`gpasswd -d ubuntu sudo`

If this command does not work, go to /etc/group find sudo group and delete ubuntu

`sudo:x:27:ubuntu,administrator`

#### 2. After ubuntu still has sudo privilege

then try 

`sudo visudo`

If there is a line

`ubuntu ALL=(ALL)    ALL`

comment or delete it